# Checking long cover of sensor

Tags: android, detection, android-sensors

I've got some probmel with checking long time cover of my sensor (which is used to turn off the screen while phone is near ear). I want to detect short and long cover of this sensor (for example by my finger). It's my code, I can detect cover but I can't check if it was long or short (I think that sth wrong is in my thread but i don't know what)

```
public class NextActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "DISTANCE";
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mProximity;
    public TextView tv;
    public TextView tv2;
    public int check=0;
    float distance=0;
    public float eventTime;
    public MyThread thread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_next);  

        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mProximity = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY);

        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        thread = new MyThread();
        thread.start();
    }


  public final void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    distance = event.values[0];
        tv.setText(""+thread.isAlive());
  }



  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    // Register a listener for the sensor.
    super.onResume();
    mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mProximity, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    // Be sure to unregister the sensor when the activity pauses.
    super.onPause();
    mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
  }

    public class MyThread extends Thread {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(true){
            if(distance<1) 
            {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                while(System.currentTimeMillis()<time+300);
                if(distance<1)
                {   
                    tv.setText("DOUBLE -> NEXT"); 
                    distance=5;
                } else tv.setText("ONCE -> BACK");      
            }else tv.setText("NONE CLICKED");
            }}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now the Thread spins constantly which is going to be bad for the battery and perhaps performance of everything else.

```
           long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
           while(System.currentTimeMillis()<time+300);
```

should be replaced with:

```
           try {
               Thread.sleep(300);
           } catch(InterruptedException ie) {}
```

The second problem is that the TextViews are not being updated in the UI thread. So a Hnadler will have to be set up to receive messges to set the text, or Runnables defined to use with runOnUiThread.